Make a p12 file available outside of my project
I have already tried this to import the p12 to keychain How to verify if my certificate is successfully added to device keychain which is working well inside the application.
Now I want to make p12 accessible outside of my project as well. (like in browser) or some other application.
I am sure if I can achieve this using above approach if not please let me know do I need to use openssl, if so I would like to know how I can use this.
I am expecting certificate to be available globally i.e outside of my project

I fixed your links but did you really mean to link to the same question twice? And what is your actual issue, it reads like you have found a solution but haven’t tried it. Is that correct and if so why haven’t you tried it?

Now I want to make p12 accessible outside of my project as well. (like in browser) or some other application. this is the main query here.

I am not able to use the certificate outside of my project/application.

Stop posting code in the comments and add it to the question instead of you think it’s relevant

You can't do this entirely in code. You can provide a link to your p12 file and when the user clicks the link they will be prompted to install the profile. They will then need to go into the settings app and trust the profile. If an app could simply install a certificate and establish trust it would be a huge security issue. Try the Charles proxy app; enable ssl proxying for an example of the process.

yes i understand we can ask user to manually trust the certificate. I am getting blob data from api which sends me p12 blob. i am using it to import in keychain. what else i need to do to make it available in settings of device.

@Paulw11 please help me in this. how to make certificate enabled for settings application of iphone

You can't do it via the Keychain API.  You will need to prepare a certificate payload and deliver it via a web link.  For example the Charles proxy sets up a VPN and then exposes the certificate profile via its internal web server.

okay but in api response i am getting blob of p12 so can I use it or i need to change that as well?

My point is you can't really do it from an app.  You need to do it from a web server, but sure, if you set up a VPN so that you can run a local web server in your app and intercept the url request then I guess you can do it from within your app with a p12.

@Paulw11 hi.. i have completed this using external link which will install my profile to user device. but is there any way to check if user has installed(trusted) it or not?
